# Using Python and Bottle to edit text data in a dictionary -- how to put the original dictionary data into the textarea?

Tags: python, html, forms, textarea, bottle

When using textarea, it's easy to put a fixed starting string into an HTML form, e.g.:

```
<form action="/whatever" method="POST">
<textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="whatever" maxlength="2500">dddddd</textarea>
</form>'''
```

and the user sees the data dddddd in the form and can edit it there.

But how can I put variable data into the form instead -- the data originally in the dictionary, so that users can start with that and make their changes? If in Python I have a variable y = 'xxx' and put y into the form, then users will see the variable name y instead of the text it contains.

Of course I could print the data and have the users cut and paste it into the form before editing, but there must be something better than that. I'd rather not require Javascript, and not require HTML5.

Comment: Are you generating the HTML with a template?  If so, you should be able to use the template to put the value of `y` in as you would with any other template value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put curly braces around the variable:

```
<form action="/whatever" method="POST">
<textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="whatever" maxlength="2500">{{y}}</textarea>
</form>
```

Check out the basic API usage in [Bottle's `SimpleTemplate` Engine documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#simpletemplate-engine).

Comment: Thank you! I thought there would be something simple.

Comment: @user3354588 Great, glad I could help. If this answer solved your question, please mark this as the correct answer so that your question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
# To help beginners, here is a minimal Python with Bottle script that runs.
# Python 3 with Bottle: How to display an HTML form pre-populated with variable data.

import bottle
from bottle import template, run
from bottle import get, post

@get('/')
def yourtest():
    x = "xxx"
    return template (ADMIN_FORM, y = x)

ADMIN_FORM = '''
    <form action="whatever" method="POST">
    <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="whatever" maxlength="2500">{{y}}</textarea>
    </form>'''

run(host='localhost', port=8080)   # Comment out for remote server.
# And run the remote server here
```